# Indexing in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have a question regarding indexing in Matlab. Suppose I have an array A=[2, 3, 6, 7]; and B is the position of the elements in A hence B=[1, 2, 3, 4]. I remove element 6 from A, therefore the resulting is A=[2 ,3 ,7] and B=[1, 2, 4]. In the next loop I want to reset value of B to B=[1, 2, 3] and if I remove 3, I have A=[2, 7] and B=[1, 3]. How do I do this?

Comment: Is this more complicated than `idx = 3; A(idx) = []; B(idx) = [];`? From this very simple example it's unclear whether you have no understanding of indexing in MATLAB (MathWorks have [good documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) for this) or whether you have a more complicated issue with a specific task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why change `A` at all? If you only change `B`, then the remaining values of `A` will always be `A(B)`.